# why( str === undefined) did not return anything

Tags: javascript, string, if-statement

```
function hey(str) {
    for (let char of str){
        if (str.slice(-1) !== "?" && str === str.toUpperCase() && str !== " "){
            return 'Whoa, chill out!';
        }
        else if (str.slice(-1) === "?" && str === str.toUpperCase()){
            return "Calm down, I know what I'm doing!";
        }
        else if(str.slice(-1) === "?" && str !== str.toUpperCase()){
            return "Sure.";
        }
        else if (str === " " || str === undefined){
            return "Fine. Be that way!";
        }
        else {
          return 'Whatever.';
        }
    }
}

hey('');
```

[link](http://exercism.io/exercises/javascript/bob/readme)

Bob
Bob is a lackadaisical teenager. In conversation, his responses are very limited.

Bob answers 'Sure.' if you ask him a question.

He answers 'Whoa, chill out!' if you yell at him.

He answers 'Calm down, I know what I'm doing!' if you yell a question at him.

He says 'Fine. Be that way!' if you address him without actually saying anything.

He answers 'Whatever.' to anything else.

Comment: what is the code supposed to do?

Comment: 1.) Remove the for loop, you don't need it

2.) I think it should work correctly if you compare to `""` instead of `" "` like:

`str === ""` and `str !== ""`

because you are calling `hey('')` and not `hey(' ')`. 

To avoid this you can use .trim() as suggested by @Erazihel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could trim the string by taking the string or an empty string and compare with logical groups.

By using a `return` statement in an `if` clause, you could omit `else`, because if `true`, the function gets terminated with `return`. For the next check, an `if` is sufficient without `else`. This method is called [*early exit*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structured_programming#Early_exit).

More to read: [Should I return from a function early or use an if statement?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/18454/should-i-return-from-a-function-early-or-use-an-if-statement)

```js
function hey(str) {
    str = (str || '').trim();
    if (str === "") {
        return "Fine. Be that way!";
    }
    if (str.slice(-1) === "?") {
        return str === str.toUpperCase()
            ? "Calm down, I know what I'm doing!"
            : "Sure.";
    }
    return str === str.toUpperCase()
        ? 'Whoa, chill out!'
        : 'Whatever.';
}

console.log(hey(''));
console.log(hey('BOA!'));
console.log(hey('BOA?'));
console.log(hey('ok!'));
console.log(hey('ok?'));
```

Answer (score 1):

They are two mistakes in your code.

- The `for` loop is unnecessary.
- You have to use the `trim` function to remove useless spaces in order to compare if what was said to Bob was an empty string or not.

```js
function hey(str) {
    const trimmedStr = (str || '').trim();
  
    if (trimmedStr === '') {
        return "Fine. Be that way!";
    }

    if (trimmedStr.slice(-1) === "?") {
      return trimmedStr === trimmedStr.toUpperCase()
        ? "Calm down, I know what I'm doing!"
        : "Sure.";
    }
     
    return trimmedStr === trimmedStr.toUpperCase()
      ? 'Whoa, chill out!'
      : 'Whatever.';
}

console.log(hey(' '));
console.log(hey('FOO?'));
console.log(hey('Foo?'));
console.log(hey('FOO'));
console.log(hey('Foo'));
```